# How to remove duplicates in a single column in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

We have a rather large spreadsheet, which could potentially have many duplicates in it.

I'm trying to find a way of highlighting and removing duplicates in a single column - take, for instance, Column B being for email address.

A person's email should only appear once, so if they appear more times in column B, then that Row X is duplicate information. Row X might contain multiple instances of the email address in Column B, depending on how the information is gathered.

Doing Conditional Formatting -> Highlight Duplicates in Excel 2010 won't work in this instance, because while Row X with 2 instances of the email address is technically a duplicate, it might not be in Column B.

Hopefully my logic makes sense.

So removing duplicates this way would remove incorrect sections.

Are there any formulas to highlight and remove duplicates that appear in Column B as opposed to duplicates in general?

Edit:
Darren Bartrup-Cook might have pointed a flaw in what I'm trying to explain -

As an example - Column B Row 21 has myemail@example.com. Depending on how the information is generated, Column G Row 21 and Column I Row 21 might have myemail@example.com.

Doing Highlight Duplicates -> Remove Duplicates might remove Column B Row 21, even though it is not a duplicate in Column B, as it does not repeat itself in any row within this.

Comment: `Row X might contain multiple instances of the email address in Column B` - do you mean it might show something like `myemail@example.com myemail@example.com` all in one cell?  If not I don't see why you can't use the `Remove Duplicates` button on the `Data` ribbon.

Comment: I'll try and elaborate further - (Damn enter being send) -But mainly because I think I might be confusing myself, so I'll update my question accordingly - Column B Row 21 has myemail@example.com. Column F Row 21 has myemail@exmaple.com and Column G Row 21 has myemail@example.com. From what I've been trying, doing Remove Duplicates would also remove the information in Column B Row 21, though Column B Row 21 might not be a duplicate in Column B.

Comment: Still doesn't make sense to me after your added explanation. Posting a simplified data set of what you have and what you are trying to achieve would probably help better than explaining with words!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you could do this using two transpose copy+pasting edits.

First, transpose your entire spreadsheet so that the rows become columns. If you don't know how to transpose: copy, paste special, check transpose.

Then, use Excel's built-in remove duplicates function.

Then, transpose your entire spreadsheet back so that the columns go back to rows. This should accomplish what you're looking for.